# Potential leak of object when calling subtreebordercolor

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am getting memory leak warnings for these two methods.  The second one calls the first one and apparently its leaking memory.  Any ideas?

```
static UIColor *subtreeBorderColor(void) 
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.5f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f];
}


- (void) updateSubtreeBorder 
{
    CALayer *layer = [self layer];
    if (layer) {


        // If the enclosing TreeGraph has its "showsSubtreeFrames" debug feature enabled, 
        // configure the backing layer to draw its border programmatically.  This is much more efficient
        // than allocating a backing store for each SubtreeView's backing layer, only to stroke a simple
        // rectangle into that backing store.

        PSBaseTreeGraphView *treeGraph = [self enclosingTreeGraph];
        if ([treeGraph showsSubtreeFrames]) {
            [layer setBorderWidth:subtreeBorderWidth()];
            [layer setBorderColor:[subtreeBorderColor() CGColor]];

        } else {
            [layer setBorderWidth:0.0];
        }


    }
}

//3: Potential leak of an object
//6: Calling 'subtreeBorderColor'
//1: Entered call from 'updateSubtreeBorder'
//13: Method returns an Objective-C object with a +0 retain count
//12: Reference count incremented. The object now has a +1 retain count
//6: Returning from 'subtreeBorderColor'
//13: Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1
```

**UPDATE 2: I just completely changed the code and deleted temporary files and cleaned the solution and this is what I see - it is finding errors where there isn't even code**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. You don't need the call to `- retain` in the function. That's **exactly** what the autorelease pattern is invented for. Since you don't create the UIColor object using alloc-init, you don't take ownership of it. No need to superfluously complicate memory management further. :)

Edit: (to prevent future downvotes) now that you edited your question and code so that it no longer erroneously returns a retained object, the previous statement is no longer valid. Yes, Xcode shows this notice about the memory leak where "there isn't even code", and that's strange. Yes, perhaps a compiler bug. Still, a temporary (and in my opinion, perfectly valid) workaround is to simply use a define instead of a function. Let's see what Xcode says if you write this instead:

```
#define SUBTREE_BORDER_COLOR [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.5f blue:0.0f alpha:1.0f]
```

Comment: @TheLearner then you're leaking memory elsewhere also. This is **THE** problem in the code *you posted.*

Comment: there are no other memory leak warnings.  see update with list of warnings AFTER removing the retain in the first method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be using "retain" the way you are, you need to also "release" the "`UIColor`" object you returned from your "`subtreeBorderColor`" method.

Were this my code, I wouldn't do "`retain`" on that autoreleased object to begin with.  Or better than that, simply do my code with ARC enabled.

Answer (score -1):

both pervious answers are right

but, if for any reason you need to retain an object being returned by your method, please follow the rules and rename your method starting with "new" (or alloc or retain or copy), so everybody (and you too) will know that the returned object is retained, so the calling code knows it's responsable to release it later, when needed...

Comment: Why did this answer get a downvote? It is not technically incorrect. Downvoter, any reasoning?

Comment: I am here to get help in order to solve my problem not to have a debate about who's answer is correct or not.  Neither answer has solved my problem

Comment: @H2CO3 let me reiterate.  I am not here to debate whether your answer was correct or not.

Comment: @TheLearner: ok, now we know why you are here. Now consider why all others are here: not just for you (i'm sorry, that may surprise you), not just for your single problem, but to get/give help one each other,  and answers may help not just the one who started the question, but all the people who may have a similar problem, so in general answers that may explain the same topic are all welcome (buy most of us, anyway). PS when you re-edit your questions after you had already some answer, please take care you didn't change the meaning of the answer too